# Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) while post_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-post

I have a strange problem

I run commands as below in local machine successfully.

```
uri = URI('http://IP/XXX/XXX.php')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'account' => Settings.account, 'orderno' => order.order_no, 'order_money' => order.total_price, 'order_user' => order.name )
```

success message as below

```
#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

However, after deploy to production machine remotely. Using same code

and I got error message as below

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:506:in `post_form'
```

I found some solutions such as

1. setting a longer timeout for nethttp request
2. use some gmes like faraday, httpclient

But I don't know that they are some good solutions.

Besides, I guess it might be a server configuration issue.

So, I try to make sure production server is able to connect to the destination server.

```
sudo traceroute -w 1 -n -T IP
```

I got these, it seems well ?

```
 traceroute to OOO.XXX.YYY (IP), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  66.212.30.225  0.564 ms  0.599 ms  0.680 ms
 2  96.44.180.41  66.869 ms  66.873 ms  67.103 ms
 3  66.186.197.173  4.233 ms  4.248 ms  4.300 ms
 4  206.223.143.104  0.656 ms  0.730 ms  0.798 ms
 5  60.199.17.57  143.147 ms  143.135 ms  143.133 ms
 6  60.199.18.157  143.067 ms  143.057 ms  143.020 ms
 7  60.199.3.221  143.014 ms  142.997 ms  142.982 ms
 8  60.199.3.142  142.994 ms 60.199.20.221  182.958 ms 60.199.23.14  143.085 ms
 9  60.199.17.118  143.338 ms 60.199.17.114  143.199 ms 60.199.17.118  143.153 ms
10  219.80.114.86  145.561 ms  145.662 ms  145.608 ms
11  211.79.200.42  145.508 ms  145.517 ms  145.473 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Also, I sent mail to destination server make sure that I follow the post rule.

I try to do my best to fix this bug but....it still there~~

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved.....

The key point is destination server blocked IP from other country.

Therefore, I asked them setup whitelist for us then problem solved.